# return a difference of nested dictionary in a new column of a spark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe where I want to find the difference in the unique_users and total_sessions for the latest day(2023-09-06) and previous day(2023-09-07) for a specific hour 2 and 13 separately for each key 'jio' and 'other' and for a specific Exception. I need to consider the Exception and Hour and Date to calculate the difference. Get the top two 'total_sessions' and unique_users.

```
Date    Hour    Exception   cell
0   2023/09/06  2   S1AP    {'design': {'jio': {'total_sessions': 39273, 'unique_users': 30837}, 'nokia': {'total_sessions': 9523, 'unique_users': 7690}}}
1   2023/09/06  13  S1AP    {'design': {'jio': {'total_sessions': 46870, 'unique_users': 39330}, 'nokia': {'total_sessions': 11745, 'unique_users': 10059}}}
2   2023/09/07  13  S1AP    {'design': {'jio': {'total_sessions': 35688, 'unique_users': 29628}, 'nokia': {'total_sessions': 8759, 'unique_users': 7537}}}
3   2023/09/07  2   S1AP    {'design': {'jio': {'total_sessions': 37804, 'unique_users': 29654}, 'nokia': {'total_sessions': 8738, 'unique_users': 7272}}}
```

I want to write a generic function that can be applied to similar columns such as `cell`.
I have other columns as well like `cell` which have long dictionaries.

I have tried the same in pandas but facing an issue with `Pyspark`.

```
# Parse JSON string and explode nested structure
df = df.withColumn("json_data", from_json(col("Cell"), StringType()))
df = df.select("Date", "Hour", "Exception", "json_data.*")
df = df.select("Date", "Hour", "Exception", explode("design").alias("vendor", "vendor_data"))

Pivot DataFrame to have separate columns for each nested key
pivot_df = df.groupBy("Date", "Hour", "Exception").pivot("vendor").agg(expr("first(vendor_data) as data"))

# Join the two DataFrames on relevant columns
joined_df = pivot_df.alias("df1").join(pivot_df.alias("df2"), ["Date", "Hour", "Exception"])

# Calculate the differences between corresponding values
diff_df = joined_df.withColumn("sessions_diff", col("jio.total_sessions") - col("nokia.total_sessions"))
diff_df = diff_df.withColumn("users_diff", col("jio.unique_users") - col("nokia.unique_users"))

# Select relevant columns
result_df = diff_df.select("Date", "Hour", "Exception", "sessions_diff", "users_diff")
```

`Expected output`:

```
 Date   Hour    Exception   IMSI_Operator   
2023-09-07 00:00:00 2   S1AP: NAS: [2] Detach   {'design': {'jio': {'total_sessions': -1469, 'unique_users': -1183}, 'nokia': {'total_sessions': -785, 'unique_users': -418}}}  
2023/09/07 0:00 13  S1AP: NAS: [2] Detach   {'design': {'jio': {'total_sessions': 11182, 'unique_users': 9702}, 'nokia': {'total_sessions': 2986, 'unique_users': 2522}}}
```